# How to push Nodes of a Binary Search Tree with same Content in a stack

Tags: java

I have a BinarySearchTree that contains people. Each person has a property of birthday month.

I have the following code trying to push Nodes to a stack if the people has the same birthday month. But when i run the program it throws a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

How can i get all elements that has the same birthday month and push them to the stack?

EDIT: Working code based ok KarlP's answer

```
//Part of the code

//Declared in Instance Variables

private Stack<BinaryNode> st = new Stack<BinaryNode>();

//Methods

public void getSame(BinaryNode node, String mo){
    if(node != null){
        if (mo.equalsIgnoreCase(node.people.getBmonth())){
            st.push(node);
        }
        getSame(node.left, mo);
        getSame(node.right, mo);
    }
}

public void getSt(String mo){
    getSame(root, mo);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not updating the `node` so it will loop for ever inside the `while` loop.

I think it probably should be replaced with an `if` statement, as a stop-condition for the recursive calls.

Comment: so replace the **while** with an _if_?

Comment: Yes.  A while statement executes the code repeatedly as long as the condition is true. An if statement does only execute the code once.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I edited my question with the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive algorithm always needs an if of some sort. Otherwise it just keeps going down.

```
if (we are done) {
    return(1);
} else {
    return recurse() + recurse();
}
```

In your case, you want to test for the lack of children nodes to end the recursion.

Use this to end the recursion:

```
if (node != null){
```